# Cannot install wine on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)

Tags: 12.04, installation

```
~/Desktop/wine-1.5.22$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

WHAT TO DO?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem installing wine on a 64-bit system and adding the official wine repo using terminal fixed it by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, first you update and upgrade your system with latest all kind of patches.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that try to install from default ubuntu repositry.
It may works.

If not, then fallow as suggested by Mr. *TenPlus1*

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

But first upgrade your system.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would stick with the stable version of wine, 1.4. The 1.5 version is a development version and is pretty buggy still. I know with the windows apps I use, for instance, there is no-right clicking ability with 1.5, but 1.4 (stable) version runs flawlessly.

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install wine1.4
```

Should see you right.